# Vlookup with prompts

Tags: vba, input, vlookup

I am currently trying to make a form in vba to request a pin from the user, and am trying to have it display the users corresponding initials, but my vlookup keeps not returning any values.

I have a worksheet titled 'userinfo'
Column A is pins, Column B is initials

I am trying to figure out a way for VBA to take the input from the prompt box, vlookup the data, and paste that resulting data into a cell.

EG
Sheet 1 = Maintenance
Press [Record Maintenance]
Box pops up prompting the users pin
User types pin
If pin is in the table for userinfo $A:$B, then copy column 2 
Paste column 2 into Cell K7 on sheet 1 (maintenance)

Comment: So what code do you have so far?

Comment: Just a little tip, don't focus too much on the vlookup. Once you learn VBA you will have no need for it. Focus on learning how to set the value from the userform as a variable, then set column A as the range, loop through all the cells in the range (use a `for each` loop), if the value matches, get the value of the cell in column B, then set the value of the cell in column K equal to this value. Figure out how to do each of these steps one by one and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

To use **VLOOKUP within VBA** code it is necessary to set **reference style to R1C1**, then it should work.

*In my opinion to use excel built-in functions like VLOOKUP will result in quicker code. On the other hand to search cells for a value in for-each loop is bad practise and if you have large amount of data it will take a lot of time.*

Here a sample code. 
It uses two sheets: UserInfo, Maintenance. The formula is set up based on template string and finally Evaluate() is called to get the result of it. HTH.

```
Public Sub test()
        Dim pin
        pin = VBA.InputBox("Enter PIN", "PIN")
        If (pin = "") Then Exit Sub

        Dim userInfoSheet As Worksheet
        Set userInfoSheet = Worksheets("UserInfo")

        Dim dataRange As Range
        Set dataRange = userInfoSheet.Columns("a:b")

        Dim initailsColumn As Byte
        initailsColumn = dataRange.Columns(2).Column

        Dim originalReferenceStyle
        originalReferenceStyle = Application.ReferenceStyle
        Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

        Dim lookup As String
        Const EXACT_MATCH As Integer = 0
        lookup = "=VLOOKUP({PIN}, {DATA_RANGE}, {INITIALS_COLUMN}, {MATCH_TYPE})"
        lookup = VBA.Replace(lookup, "{PIN}", pin)
        lookup = VBA.Replace(lookup, "{DATA_RANGE}", dataRange.Worksheet.Name & "!" & dataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1))
        lookup = VBA.Replace(lookup, "{INITIALS_COLUMN}", initailsColumn)
        lookup = VBA.Replace(lookup, "{MATCH_TYPE}", EXACT_MATCH)

        Dim result As Variant
        result = Application.Evaluate(lookup)

        Application.ReferenceStyle = originalReferenceStyle

        If (Not VBA.IsError(result)) Then
            Dim maintenanceSheet As Worksheet
            Set maintenanceSheet = Worksheets("Maintenance")
            maintenanceSheet.Range("k7").Value = result
        Else
            Dim parsedError As String
            parsedError = ParseEvaluateError(result)
            MsgBox "Error: " & parsedError, vbExclamation, "Error"
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Function ParseEvaluateError(ByRef errorValue As Variant) As String
        Dim errorNumber As Long
        Dim errorMessage As String

        errorNumber = VBA.CLng(errorValue)
        Select Case errorNumber
            Case 2000:
                errorMessage = "#NULL!"
            Case 2007:
                errorMessage = "#DIV/0!"
            Case 2015:
                errorMessage = "#VALUE!"
            Case 2023:
                errorMessage = "#REF!"
            Case 2029:
                errorMessage = "#NAME?"
            Case 2036:
                errorMessage = "#NUM!"
            Case 2042:
                errorMessage = "#N/A"
            Case Else
                errorMessage = "Unknow"
        End Select
        ParseEvaluateError = errorMessage
    End Function
```

Comment: That's some solid code you have there. I do agree with your comment that it is generally bad practice to use a `for each` loop to search cells (I personally would utilize the `Search` object which would be a lot quicker on large datasets). I didn't suggest that in my comment above because it appears the OP is just starting to learn the fundamentals of VBA and setting the `Search` object is probably a little too advanced. My thinking was that the OP would benefit more by learning the basics such as setting range objects and understanding how loops work.

Comment: @UberNubIsTrue: yes it's OK to start with for-each. I have just tried to answer the question about the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to Daniel's solution. There is nothing wrong with Daniel's but I wanted to show a solution without using the `Vlookup` function. By eliminating the `Vlookup` function you will not have to handle the different error messages that the function can return. This is strictly personal preference.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()
Dim PIN As Variant
Dim WRKSHT_USERINFO As Excel.Worksheet
Dim WRKSHT_MAINTENANCE As Excel.Worksheet
Dim COLUMN_WITH_INITIALS As Long
Dim CELL_WITH_INITIALS_MATCHING_PIN As Range
Dim DESTINATION_CELL As Range

PIN = VBA.InputBox("Enter PIN", "PIN")
If PIN = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

Set WRKSHT_USERINFO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("userinfo")
Set WRKSHT_MAINTENANCE = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Maintenance")
Set DESTINATION_CELL = WRKSHT_MAINTENANCE.Range("K7")

COLUMN_WITH_INITIALS = 2 ''Column B

Set CELL_WITH_INITIALS_MATCHING_PIN = Get_Cell_With_Initials(WRKSHT_USERINFO, PIN, COLUMN_WITH_INITIALS)

If CELL_WITH_INITIALS_MATCHING_PIN Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox "No Records Found For PIN: " & PIN
   Exit Sub
Else
   WRKSHT_MAINTENANCE.Range(DESTINATION_CELL.Address).Value =  CELL_WITH_INITIALS_MATCHING_PIN.Value
End If

End Sub

Function Get_Cell_With_Initials(ByRef WRKSHT_USERINFO As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal PIN As  Variant, ByVal COLUMN_WITH_INITIALS As Long) As Range
Dim SEARCH_OBJECT As Object
Dim ROW_WITH_VALUE As Long

Set SEARCH_OBJECT = Cells.Find(What:=PIN, After:=WRKSHT_USERINFO.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)

If SEARCH_OBJECT Is Nothing Then
    Exit Function
Else
    ROW_WITH_VALUE = SEARCH_OBJECT.Row
End If

Set Get_Cell_With_Initials = WRKSHT_USERINFO.Cells(ROW_WITH_VALUE, COLUMN_WITH_INITIALS)

End Function
```